# What pest is producing this "grit"

Tags: pest

Something is leaving grit beside our skirtingboard (baseboard?). There is a 1/4 inch gap between the baseboard and the floor.

What is producing the grit? Would sealing the gap help?

FYI: House is in Ireland, built early 2000s

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow... how long has it taken for that quantity to appear?

Comment: We were away from the house for 6 weeks. But we do see the grit there regularly at other times in much smaller quantities.

Comment: Where does the trail start and stop? Given the proximity to the wall it's probably mice running back and forth and tracking dirt from the outside. Does any of it look like mouse poop? Can you shine a black light on your floor? Mice genitals rub against the ground so you should see trails of urine everywhere.

Comment: I have seen homes fully infested with mice that don't have dirt piles like that. Feces yes, dirt no. Are you certain there's not a gap near the wall? Perhaps a landscaper is using a leaf blower and dirt is blown into your house.

Comment: How old is the house? Looks kind of like vermiculite insulation.

Comment: Agree with gunner / this was a popular material in my youth,,, 60-70s but still doing it

Comment: Built early 2000s. Has glass fibre insulation. No gap near the wall for dirt to blow in from outside.

Comment: Can we see a wider view including the entire wall and ceiling above this?